# Custom grouped UItableview from database

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uitableview, sqlite

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6013744/2.png
I have to create similar  medicine list form.
i dont know how to put arrow, cross images in left. I can click them and take value of that to next page.
I also want make grouped view.Disease in header and medicine related to that in row

I know how to insert field in database and view value on tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create selected and deselected images of those arrows and cross. Set the deselected image on a custom button. On selection change its image to the selected image. This will simulate the effect that you require.